# SEO with Static AngularJS Site

Tags: angularjs, seo, phantomjs, prerender

I have a site AngularJS that is static and is being hosted on GoDaddy. All of the articles I have seen recommend using some sort of middleware service such as Prerender or PhantomJS. As this isn't an option for me, Google has started to crawl my site and is displaying curly braces in my search results.

I have tried a few things...

I have tried setting up ngMeta (https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta) but Google does not seem to be crawling these dynamic tags properly.

In each of the routes, I have configured the meta tags properly and have initialized it on the run function...

```
...
meta: {
  'title': 'My Title',
  'description': 'My description'
}
...

.run(['ngMeta', function(ngMeta) { 
    ngMeta.init();
}]);
```

I have also tried to upload a site map but that didn't seem to help.

The site is simple (5 pages) and is all top level routes. There are no nested routes, so it should be easy for Google to crawl.

How can I "prerender" or at least set up this static site in a way that is SEO friendly? I've been looking for solutions but I feel like I've exhausted all options. Thanks in advance.